# Print 10 x 10 co-ordinates grid

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am printing a grid that is displayed from 0 - 9 for columns and 0- 9 for the rows.

I am wanting to display it as 0 - 9 for columns and A - J for rows but am unsure how to use a character instead of an Integer in the loops?

```
public class BattleshipGame {

private char[][] playerBoard;   
private char[][] compBoard;     
private final static int boardSize = 10;
private String input, shipType, shipDirection = ""; 
public static String name;      
private int shipRowLoc, shipColLoc; 
private boolean allowed, random = false, showShips = false;
private MoveType moveType;
private ArrayList<Battleships> enemyShips = new ArrayList<Battleships>();

Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

public BattleshipGame() {
    playerBoard = new char[boardSize][boardSize];
    compBoard = new char[boardSize][boardSize];
    initializeBoard();  
    placeShip();    
}

public void initializeBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++){
            playerBoard[i][j] = '~';
            compBoard[i][j] = '~';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few choices, you might use

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'J'; ch++)
```

or something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  char ch = (char) ('A' + j);
```

Answer (score 1):

To map characters `A`-`J` from `int`s you can probably just index them at their code point.

For instance, `A` is `65`.

So `System.out.println((char)65)` will print `A`.

Increment it by your index from `0` to `9`, and you'll get characters from `A` to `J`.